# Finding value in Data Frame and cross referencing value in corresponding column

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing

I have a Data Frame as follows:

```
Index   X_1  X_2  X_3  W_1   W_2   W_3
1       IEZ  XOP  ABC  0.42  0.18  0.40
2       PXJ  ABC  XES  0.47  0.12  0.41
3       ABC  RYE  PXE  0.23  0.33  0.44
4       XOP  IEZ  ABC  0.62  0.20  0.18
```

I want to go through each index row for each instance of "ABC" between the columns X_1 to X_3. For each instance, I would like to extract the corresponding value from columns W_1 to W_3 and append it to a new column W.

For example, for index row 1 if an instance of ABC appears in X_3, it would extract the corresponding value from W_3.

The ending product should look like this.

```
Index   X_1  X_2  X_3  W_1   W_2    W_3     **W**
1       IEZ  XOP  ABC  0.42  0.18   0.40    **0.40**
2       PXJ  ABC  XES  0.47  0.12   0.41    **0.12**
3       ABC  RYE  PXE  0.23  0.33   0.44    **0.23**
4       XOP  IEZ  ABC  0.62  0.20   0.18    **0.18**
```

**How can I do this only with the numpy and pandas modules imported?**

Comment: Maybe you can stack the columns and make a new DataFrame. For example, new column X stacks X_1, X_2, and X_3. Then, new column W stacks W_1, W_2, and W_3. Now, you can simple filter for df[df[‘X’]==‘ABC’][‘W’].

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I am sure there is a better way, but:

```
x_cols = [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('X_')]
res_dfs = []
for col in x_cols:
    idx = col.split("_")[1]
    xw = df[col, "W_{idx}]
    xw = xw.loc[xw[col]  == 'ABC']
    xw = xw[[f"W_{idx}"]].rename(columns={f"W_{idx}": 'W'})
    res = df.join(xw).dropna()
    res_dfs.append(res)
df = pd.concat(res_dfs)
```

Basically I iterate over the x cols and their matching w cols, locate where the x value is 'abc' and fill a new 'w' column with the matching w value.

It is from my cellphone so I could not try it, but that is the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# df is your dataframe

# idxs = np.argwhere(df.values == "ABC") will also work
# if "ABC" only appears once per row.
idxs = np.argwhere(df.values[:, :3] == "ABC")
idxs[:, 1] += 3
w = df.values[idxs[:, 0], idxs[:, 1]]
df = df.assign(W=w)
```

or

```
matches = df.iloc[:, :3] == "ABC"
w = df.iloc[:, 3:].values[matches]
df = df.assign(W=w)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X_1' : ['IEZ', 'PXJ', 'ABC', 'XOP'],  
                   'X_2' : ['XOP', 'ABC', 'RYE', 'IEZ'], 
                   'X_3' : ['ABC', 'XES','PXE', 'ABC'],
                   'W_1' :  [0.42, 0.47, 0.23, 0.62],
                   'W_2' : [0.18, 0.12, 0.33, 0.20],
                   'W_3' :  [0.40, 0.41, 0.44, 0.18]})
```

Firstly, take the numerical columns:

```
num_columns = df.loc[:,'W_1':'W_3']
```

Next, generate a boolean mask, using `X_1`->`X_3` columns:

```
df_mask = (df.loc[:,'X_1':'X_3']=='ABC').values
```

Finally, use the the DataFrame mask method which will return NaNs when the cell is True and the cell value when the mask is False. We will then sum the resulting rows and assign this to the original DataFrame:

```
df['W'] = num_columns.mask(~df_mask).sum(axis=1)
```

Of course this can be combined into a single line:

```
df['W'] = (df.loc[:,'W_1':'W_3']
            .mask(~(df.loc[:,'X_1':'X_3']=='ABC').values)
            .sum(axis=1))
```

**Edit:**

Of course, this will only work if there is only one instance of `'ABC'` per row - you may want to run a check for this.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pd.DataFrame.where` with boolean indexing:

```
df1, df2 = df[[c for c in df if c[0]=='X']], df[[c for c in df if c[0]=='W']]
df["W"] = df2.where((df1 == 'ABC').values).sum(1)
print(df)
   Index  X_1  X_2  X_3   W_1   W_2   W_3     W
0      1  IEZ  XOP  ABC  0.42  0.18  0.40  0.40
1      2  PXJ  ABC  XES  0.47  0.12  0.41  0.12
2      3  ABC  RYE  PXE  0.23  0.33  0.44  0.23
3      4  XOP  IEZ  ABC  0.62  0.20  0.18  0.18
```

This works on an assumption that `df1` and `df2` always have a same shape.